# How to add value next to points for a plot of a time series in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to add the values of forecasted time series to a plot in r.

I have

```
par(mfrow = c(1,1))

plot(train,type='l',xlim=c(2017,2019.5),ylim=c(75,200),xlab = 'Year',ylab = 'Sales')

title(main="13 Month Sales Forecast")

lines(e, col='green')

points(train, pch=19)

points(e,col='green' ,pch=19)
```

Where e is the time series consisting of the values I want and train is the data I have used to produce the model.

The current code above produces the graph I want except I want to display the values of the time series prediction e by the points.

I tried `text(e)` and that puts the numbers on the points but the numbers are 1,2,3,... and so on not the values of the forecast that the time series, e,  contains.

Comment: Not reproducible. Please post, **in the question**, the output of `dput(train)` and the code that produces `e`.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitely add argument `label` in `text` as below:

```
 # Train data.frame simulation
set.seed(123)
year = seq(2017, 2019.5, length.out = 20)
Sales = seq(75, 200, length.out = 20)
train <- data.frame(year, Sales)

# Source data simulation
year = seq(2017, 2019.5, length.out = 10)
Sales_source = seq(75, 200, length.out = 10) + rnorm(10) * 10
e <- data.frame(year, Sales_source)


# plotting
par(mfrow = c(1,1))

plot(train, type="l", xlim = c(2017, 2019.5), 
     ylim = c(75, 200), xlab = "Year", ylab = "Sales")

title(main = "13 Month Sales Forecast")
lines(e, col = "green")
points(train, pch = 19)
points(e, col = "green", pch = 19)

# Adding labels
text(e, labels = ceiling(Sales_source), pos = 2)
```

Output:
[image: forecast]